# I have a problem with steam launching in archlinux

Tags: steam, pc, linux

Every single time than I try to launch steam it throws a `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries` followed by a `Failed to load steamui.so` error.

```
$steam-runtime
Running Steam on arch rolling 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
libpcre.so.1
libmount.so.1
libsystemd.so.0
libdrm.so.2
/home/ulises/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1576550254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1576550254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1576550254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1576550254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1576550254)
Failed to load steamui.so - dlerror(): libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
[2019-12-30 14:31:15] Startup - updater built Dec 16 2019 16:48:42
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2019-12-30 14:31:15] Checking for update on startup
[2019-12-30 14:31:15] Checking for available updates...
[2019-12-30 14:31:15] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2019-12-30 14:31:24] Download failed: http error 0 (client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2019-12-30 14:31:24] Downloading manifest: media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Download failed: http error 0 (media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Failed to load manifest
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Error: Download failed: http error 0
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Verifying installation...
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2019-12-30 14:31:33] Verification complete
[2019-12-30 14:31:39] Shutdown
```

Comment: This question would probably be more suitable for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on a similar issue on this [ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157825) :

Rename your `~/.steam` hidden folder to `~/.steam-old` (or something else different from original name), and start steam again. It would repair your installation and re-download your Steam client.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to run Steam using your distribution's native libraries. Install the necessary 32-bit libraries (packages are usually named `lib32-<libname>`), then run `env GDK_SCALE=1 /usr/bin/steam-native %U`.